# Storing data while processing an app through phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the Phonegap platform for developing an app and this runs on nexus 5 android 4.
The app is having a user interface through which it takes input from the user and processes it using the Javascript. My question is: Can I store/capture this data somewhere so that I can utilize it later. The utility can be sending the captured data to another server and getting a response from it for the specific data.

What is the best architectural way to accomplish this? Any thoughts highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to do this, IndexedDB, SQLite, localStorage, sessionStorage which are all HTML5 standards.

You might even be able to use XML file storage to do this.

Its your preference on what works best for you.